# Variable not storing the data it is assigned on a STM32 using c++

Tags: c++, variables, variable-assignment, stm32

I am working on my first project using an STM32F103 microcontroller. I am trying to read the temperature and to print it out every second. The code seems to do its job sometimes but on a few occasions the function returns 0 when it clearly should not return 0.

I have defined the `last_values` to be fixed values so that the calculation should allways be a positive number.

The function where things seem to mess up:

```
float TempSensor::getTemp() {
    uint32_t average = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < AVERAGE_SIZE; index++)
        average += last_values[index];


    float average_val = average / AVERAGE_SIZE;
    
    printf("Value %f, Address %p\n\r", average_val, (void*) &average_val);
    printf("Average: %lu/%d=%f\n\r", average, AVERAGE_SIZE, average_val);
    
    float result = 1 / (1 / (T0 + 273.15) + (log(((average_val * R1) / (ADC_RES - average_val)) / R0)) / B) - 273.15;
    return result < 0 ? -25.0 : result;
}
```

The tempp_sensor.h file:

```
#ifndef INC_JEMINA_TEMP_SENSOR_H_
#define INC_JEMINA_TEMP_SENSOR_H_

#include "Jemina/Jemina.h"
#include "math.h"

const uint8_t AVERAGE_SIZE = 5;

//extern ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc1;

class TempSensor {
private:
    uint8_t channel;
    uint32_t last_values[AVERAGE_SIZE] = { 1111 , 2222, 3333, 4444, 5555};

public:
    static uint32_t value[4];
    TempSensor(uint8_t channel);
    float getTemp();
    void readTemp();
    static void init();
};

#endif /* INC_JEMINA_TEMP_SENSOR_H_ */
```

The function call using an interrupt on timer 6

```
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim) {
    if (htim == &htim6) { //Gets called once every second
        printf("H0 temp: %f\n\n\r", H0_TEMP.getTemp());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Value 3333.000000, Address 0x2000bf68
Average: 16665/5=3333.000000
H0 temp: 65.428040

Value 3333.000000, Address 0x2000bf88
Average: 16665/5=3333.000000
H0 temp: 65.428040

Value 0.000000, Address 0x40aa0a00
Average: 16665/5=0.000000
H0 temp: 0.000000

Value 0.000000, Address 0x40aa0a00
Average: 16665/5=0.000000
H0 temp: 0.000000

Value 3333.000000, Address 0x2000bf88
Average: 16665/5=3333.000000
H0 temp: 65.428040

Value 3333.000000, Address 0x2000bf88
Average: 16665/5=3333.000000
H0 temp: 65.428040

Value 0.000000, Address 0x40aa0a00
Average: 16665/5=0.000000
H0 temp: 0.000000

Value 3333.000000, Address 0x2000bf88
Average: 16665/5=3333.000000
H0 temp: 65.428040

Value 0.000000, Address 0x40aa0a00
Average: 16665/5=0.000000
H0 temp: 0.000000

Value 0.000000, Address 0x40aa0a00
Average: 16665/5=0.000000
H0 temp: 0.000000

Value 3333.000000, Address 0x2000bf88
Average: 16665/5=3333.000000
H0 temp: 65.428040

Value 0.000000, Address 0x40aa0a00
Average: 16665/5=0.000000
H0 temp: 0.000000

Value 3333.000000, Address 0x2000bf88
Average: 16665/5=3333.000000
H0 temp: 65.428040

Value 3333.000000, Address 0x2000bf88
Average: 16665/5=3333.000000
H0 temp: 65.428040

Value 3333.000000, Address 0x2000bf88
Average: 16665/5=3333.000000
H0 temp: 65.428040

Value 3333.000000, Address 0x2000bf88
Average: 16665/5=3333.000000
H0 temp: 65.428040

Value 3333.000000, Address 0x2000bf88
Average: 16665/5=3333.000000
H0 temp: 65.428040

Value 3333.000000, Address 0x2000bf88
Average: 16665/5=3333.000000
H0 temp: 65.428040

Value 0.000000, Address 0x40aa0a00
Average: 16665/5=0.000000
H0 temp: 0.000000

Value 3333.000000, Address 0x2000bf88
Average: 16665/5=3333.000000
H0 temp: 65.428040

Value 3333.000000, Address 0x2000bf88
Average: 16665/5=3333.000000
H0 temp: 65.428040

Value 3333.000000, Address 0x2000bf88
Average: 16665/5=3333.000000
H0 temp: 65.428040

Value 0.000000, Address 0x40aa0a00
Average: 16665/5=0.000000
H0 temp: 0.000000

Value 0.000000, Address 0x40aa0a00
Average: 16665/5=0.000000
H0 temp: 0.000000
```

As you can see the `average_val` should allways be 16665/5=3333.0 but sometimes it remains 0.0. One thing I noticed is that the address is also different when the calculation seems to go wrong.

Does anyone know why this happens and how I can fix it?

Comment: Tell-tale signs of [demons flying out of everyone's nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) due to undefined behavior somewhere in your program. The bug can be anywhere, and I doubt that anyone will be able to tell you why, since it will be necessary to attempt to analyze and debug the entire program in order to isolate the bug.

Comment: The large difference between the stack addresses suggests multiple threads are involved, and so does the comment about interrupts. Don't know enough about the STM32 environment to guess whether calling `printf` from an interrupt handler is even legal, but in any case the question needs a lot more code and context than provided.

Comment: ... or a lot less code. Do you get the same problem if you just read the sensor in a loop where you sleep 1 second between reading?

Comment: I removed the printf statements from the functions and added a global variable to store the value in stead of printing it in the interrupt handler. When I print the value in the loop everything seems to work properly. Guess that calling printf in an interrupt caused the problem then. 

Thank you for your replies!

Comment: Just a note: Strangely, `0x40aa0a00` is not even a valid address for STM32F103. It's not in the SRAM area where the stack is allocated. `0x40000000` is the start of peripheral registers, but they don't seem to reach `0x40aa0a00`.